# Here-String prints extra lines when piped to Out-File

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to programattically create a file using Powershell (I know, noob stuff) with multiple lines of content.

My attempt is as follows:

```
$ServicesYaml = @'
parameters:
  twig.config:
    debug: true
    auto-reload: true
    cache: false
'@
$ServicesYaml | Out-File -FilePath .\services.yml
```

This seems fine when printing to the console using `Write-Output`:
[image: Here-String Console Output]

But prints out extra lines when sending to a file: (Viewed using Atom):
[image]

What am I doing wrong? I obviously don't want all of the unprintable and extra whitespace that appears to be getting printed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a clash of linuxy nature of GIT and Windows text file byte order mark. The Out-File commandlet uses a Windows encoding (USC-2 LE BOM) that GIT does not supports and GIT treats the file as binary instead of text. Try using Set-Content commandlet which uses UTF-8 without [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)

```
$ServicesYaml = '
parameters:
    twig.config:
    debug: true
    auto-reload: true
    cache: false
'
$ServicesYaml | Set-Content -FilePath .\services.yml
```

Comment: You can also use the `-Encoding` parameter with either `Out-File` or `Set-Content` to control the encoding.

Comment: Worth noting: the final line can also be written as `Set-Content -Path .\services.yml -Value $ServicesYaml`